# Linux equivalent of the Mac OS X "open" command

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, command-line-interface

I've found the "open" command in Mac OS X very handy in the command line. From "man open":

> The `open` command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had
>       double-clicked the file's icon. If no application name is specified, the
>       default application as determined via LaunchServices is used to open the
>       specified files.

That is, if I want to open a PDF file with the default PDF viewer (happens to be Preview), I only need to do:

```
open my.pdf
```

In Linux, however, to open a PDF file from the command line, I had to dig around to find the default PDF viewer is, for instance, "evince" (who'd have guessed??), and then

```
evince my.pdf
```

So, is there a simple equivalent of the 'open' command in the Linux command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this question should be moved over to superuser.com?

Comment: Super User seems inappropriate - is there a StackOverflow for "ordinary users" or possibly "programmers who want to script other applications", i.e. automate?

Comment: askubuntu might fit.

Comment: It seems perfectly relevant to Stack Overflow to me.  I'm using it in a script I'm writing to support opening URLs to work on multiple platforms.  This isn't the first time I've wound up here from Google either.  

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You could try `xdg-open`, most Linux distros have it. It will open default associated app for your file.

FYI https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-open.html

Comment: A big difference between this and `open`, however, is that this doesn't open the file/app in the background. Linux apps seem to be very chatty and often output multiple lines of diagnostics and warnings right into your terminal (even though nothing really went wrong). I usually have to do something like `xdg-open <file> &> /dev/null &` instead. Is there anything better than xdg-open in this regard?

Comment: @Suan: It does open the app in the "background", detached from terminal, in a way you may continue working in the terminal as soon as the app is launched. So the trailing  `&` is not needed. As for the "multiple lines of diagnostics", those are from the app itself, not from `xdg-open`. If you don't want any output, you would need `&> /dev/null` even using `evince` directly (OP's example), so your complain is void. `xdg-open` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: @MestreLion I don't think the complaint is entirely void, since Mac's open does not result in application output being echoed to the terminal.

Comment: @MaxNanasy: output is from applications, it is not `xdg-open`'s fault if *they* are chatty. And suppressing such messages should be *user's* choice, not xdg's. So it is a void complain to ask for something "better" than `xdg-open`. Also, if Mac's `open` has no option to output those messages, I'd say that `open`is *much worse* than `xdg-open`, since when you use command line to launch files you're usually interested in that output (otherwise, why not simply double-clicking the file in a browser like Nautilus?)

Comment: @MestreLion The use case I, and probably most Mac users, most often use `open` for is if I'm already using a terminal, but want to open a file with a GUI application (e.g. I'm in a folder with an image I want to view, so I run `open image.png`, rather than re-navigating to the folder in Finder).  If I do want to view debug messages from a GUI application, I open Console, which has a Console Log view that shows messages from all running applications.

Comment: @MestreLion PS: I'm not saying that `open` is better or worse than `xdg-open`: I'm just denying that Suan's complaint is void, since the two systems have different behavior, and Suan prefers one aspect of one system's behavior.

Comment: @MestreLion Although one could make the case that the complaint is trivial, since `alias open='xdg-open &>/dev/null'` yields approximately the desired behavior (although errors from xdg-open itself (as opposed to just the launched program) would also be silenced, which is undesirable).

Comment: @MaxNanasy: we both agree that the only difference in each tool is their default behavior regarding output: `open` by default silences output (is there a way to make "un-silence" it?), while `xdg-open`, as most linux terminal tools, does not silence its application's output. And it is a sensible default, IMHO, since A) It is trivial  to disable it yourself, if you want to; B) apps may output important messages, not only debug diags and warnings

Comment: xdg-open doesn't open multiple files like "open" on OSX: `open image*.jpg`

A workaround may be needed: `ls *.jpg | while read -r file; do xdg-open "$file"; done`

Comment: how about "open -a", im trying to solve this problem but on linux http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75221/how-to-drop-a-file-onto-a-gui-app-from-command-line

Comment: Mac name it 'open'. Ubuntu name it 'xdg-open'. Who is the one give that ugly name. Why not using like 'zSy-#d%^-open' to make it harder another level, for something that so trivial.

Comment: @nafsaka one reason might be that `open` is already referenced on multiple sections in the man pages as a c function and `xdg-open` didn't want to conflict with them. *shurgs

Answer (score 82):

The equivalent you are looking for is [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html), which can be used in the same way as OS X's `open` command. For example:

```
xdg-open ~/Documents/Chubby_Bubbies.odt
```

However, this is really hard to type quickly and accurately. Instead, you should make an alias to xdg-open, which makes the process much quicker.

Of course, you can alias it to `open` to make it match OS X (you can pick anything you want), but personally, I use the right square bracket (`]`) for my shortcut for speed reasons. To use this, add the following to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias ']'='xdg-open'
```

Then, to open any resource, use it like any of these examples:

```
] www.google.com
] file.txt
] ~/Pictures
] ssh://myserver.local/home/jeremy
```

Also this lets you open a file browser (e.g. Nautilus) in the current directory:

```
] .
```

From experience I have found that one-letter aliases work best for the above shortcut. After all, the goal is efficiency. And you can go back and make the same alias on OS X — I leave that as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Comment: I made an alias from 'open' to 'xdg-open' in order to have it consistent on both Linux and Mac.

Comment: Thats good but not great, I tried to open an .url file and opened it in gedit.

Comment: @sorin : `xdg-open` opens your system's default application for the file. In your case, `.url` files are set to open in gedit. If you want to change that, right-click the file in Nautilus and go to Properties > Open With to change the default application, and `xdg-open` will work accordingly.

Comment: [Here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/ozanmuyes/ea92b8eaba34d9c57894f05751270118) that I've made, just copy-paste and execute command under 'Altogether' section in the first comment.

Comment:  for Chubby Bubbies! lol nifty alias @ozanmuyes cool script, I [ported to zsh](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/3ad934aab2017bcb788deb66778ef26d), there was a minor bug but it didn't break anything, works.

Answer (score 17):

I just sorted this out myself so thought I would write down how I did it, which is specifically relevant to what Suan asked.
These steps allow you just type "open " and not your terminal covered in messages you don't need:

Create a script called `open` in `~/bin`, the content is just:

```
xdg-open "$1" &> /dev/null &
```

Save and close the script, then type "source .profile" (or .bash_profile if relevant).
Thats it so typing "open Music" will open your music folder in the nautilus GUI and shouldn't enter anything onto your terminal.

Comment: What's with the alias and the weird location? Just call the script itself `open` and put it in your PATH (typically in `$HOME/bin/open`)

Comment: On my machine (ubuntu 11.10) if you add a script called 'open' to your path, and try to do that way it is overidden by /bin/open. So I can't work out a way of getting your way to work without an alias.

Comment: The trick is to have your own script in a directory which comes earlier in your `PATH` than `/bin`.  By convention, if you have `$HOME/bin` it would be added to the beginning of the PATH, before any system directories.  Commonly, this is done by your `.profile` or similar.  For example, the default `.profile` on Ubuntu does exactly this.

Comment: Redirecting output to `/dev/null` is a bit capricious; perhaps you could redirect output to `$HOME/.xsession-errors` or some such, so that diagnostics are not completely lost in case you need to troubleshoot something.

Comment: I had to use "$1" instead of $1 (including the quotes) to stop xdg-open from being confused about spaces in filenames.

Comment: @efdee: properly quoting *all* variables is a good programming practice, and vital in bash scripts. This has nothing to do with `xdg-open`, this is a shell issue.

Comment: Also, the `&` in the end is not needed: `xdg-open` in gnome uses `gvfs-open`, which already opens applications in the background. And IMHO the redirection should not be used: opening files in terminal usually means you *are* interested in debug/error messages. Otherwise, why not simply use Nautilus instead?

Comment: On Mac Finder remembers the view settings (sidebar, toolbar, view mode etc) per directory. I think it stores those in a hidden file (.DS_Store perhaps?). It even remembers the state of opened/closed items in the tree view! So when I worked on a Git repo with Vim, I usually typed "open ." to get started. It would open a nice treeview without all the cruft (sidebar/toolbar), and it would always open where it was the last time. Essentially a really nice and handy way of browsing my repo and drag/dropping files into Vim (I love Vim but I hate the stupid text mode windows).

Comment: The `xdg-open` doesn't always run it in the background, I'm currently using KDE. Also `xdg-open` isn't exactly equivalent to `open` or Cygwin's `cygstart`. The application being opened should open completely independently from the terminal, and not be part of the process tree of the terminal, which means it should be detached, and its error output should flow to `~/.xsession-errors`.

Comment: Also `xdg-open` doesn't open `*.desktop` files currently. So I can't just open an application as is, without opening a file association.

Comment: In my ~/.zshrc I've added: `alias open="xdg-open &>/dev/null "`.

Answer (score 11):

Traditionally, you can use the "see" command. Which just uses run-mailcap. This will work without Gnome and X etc.

```
man see
```

Comment: The problem is `run-mailcap` (and its many aliases) uses a separate (and terribly outdated) app association database. For example in my system, while `.mp3` songs correctly open in VLC, `.txt` files open in less (instead of gedit) and `.pdf` files simply fail to open! ( Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/pdf")

Comment: As I said, it depends on each system. Few applications register themselves in a way `run-mailcap` recognizes them. `xdg-open` internally uses `gvfs-open` (on Gnome systems like Ubuntu), which in turn uses xdg's mime-database spec, which far more applications use.

Comment: Opened a 50+ page PDF in `gimp` for me.  I'll stick with `xdg-open`.

Comment: Opening txt files in `less` x''D

Answer (score 4):

gnome-open

Comment: gnome-open is now deprecated, and besides it was already used internally by `xdg-open` if the user was on Gnome (now it uses `gvfs-open`)

Answer (score 2):

If you have your mimes setup correctly, you can use `mimeopen`. Check out its man page, since it has some useful options.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer was expanded. I'd be interested to see how this works

Answer (score -3):

Under Gnome Desktop environment, I use the following command:

```
nautilus `pwd` &
```

This is similar as "open ." command in Mac

Comment: This answer has multiple issues: A) It opens the current directory, not the file, as user requested. B) you can use `.` instead of "``pwd``" C) if you change `pwd` for a file, user would still need to hit ENTER after Nautilus opens D) Opening nautilus first just for *it* to open the file is a very indirect solution.