# Windows cygwin equivalent of Mac OS X open command

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin, command-line-interface

I realize this is almost identical to [Windows equivalent of the Mac OS X “open” command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501290/windows-equivalent-of-the-mac-os-x-open-command) and [Linux equivalent of the Mac OS X "open" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264395/linux-equivalent-of-the-mac-os-x-open-command), but I'm asking specifically about a command I can run in the Cygwin shell to use the current Windows UI application bound for the argument's extension, that as on OS X opens that application if necessary, and opens the specified file in that application.

The cmd.exe start command isn't an option in the Cygwin shell, nor are xdg-open or gnome-open available through Cygwin.

Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have missed this one:

[Open a file from Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577595/open-a-file-from-cygwin)

Comment: Yup, both manual and automatic search didn't find that one. Thanks.

Comment: For people too lazy to follow links, the command referenced above is "cygstart".