# How to open file in mac using a fscommand in flash cs3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have created an application in Flash cs3. In that application I have to open a pdf file in Acrobat Reader. I have used this to open a file

```
openPdf1.addEventListener
    (MouseEvent.CLICK,
    function ():void
{
    fscommand ("exec", "manual.bat");
}
);
```

but now when I am going to Mac OS then this code is not working, which means the file is not open

So how can I open files in Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac won't execute a batch file you need to change the batch file into a shell script (at the very least) http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html

Comment: in the batch file i use this code                                     @echo off
start foldername. so can you please tell me that how can i cornvert in to the shell script. i dont have any about it.

Comment: can you post the batch file contents? or is that all?

Comment: @echo off
start Catalogue.pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264395/linux-equivalent-of-the-mac-os-x-open-command also change the extension of the manual.bat to manual.sh

Comment: that is a contents of my batch file.

Comment: yah try to change the contents to be
"open Catalogue.pdf"
and change the file extension from .bat to .sh and I think it'll work (maybe :)