# How to get list of programs associated with a certain extension?

Tags: c++, file, qt, file-extension

For example, for `.png` I'd like to receive `mspaint`, `ois`, `chrome` (these are programs that can view png files on my Windows machine).

Of course there is always

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\.png\\OpenWithList`

but I'm looking for a cross platform way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross platform way, according to [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32300-System-File-Association). But you could use some platform-specific ways that do similar things. For example, you could use the `open` command on OS X, or `xdg-open` for Linux (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264395/linux-equivalent-of-the-mac-os-x-open-command)). It looks like you already know how to do it on Windows, which is good because I don't.

For example:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__

void open_image(){
    system("open someimage.png");
}

#endif
```

Comment: He wants to get a *list* of associated programs, not opening the file with the default program.