# Click local file link and open in default file handler

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R-Shiny package which creates a visualization.

This is working fine, except that, I wish to present a clickable link to a local disk file and have that file open with whatever application is registered for that type of file ?

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Clickable Link to Open Local File"),
  useShinyjs(),
  br(),
  actionButton("open_file_button", "Open File"),
  hidden(tags$a(id = "file_link", href = "", target = "_blank")),
  hidden(textOutput("file_path_text"))
)
```

I have read that this is basically an issue with the fact that the browser rendering Shiny is not allowed to open files because that would be a security breach.

The point is, this tool I am writing is designed to be used by R developers on their local machine, so they already have access to those files anyway.

Is there another UI package I should be using instead of Shiny (or maybe as well as)?
Is there some standard way to make this work using Shiny ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If all devs are running windows, you may be able to hack something using `shell.exec`; on non-windows platforms, that function is not defined, so it is OS-dependent. On other OSes you may be able to hobble combinations of ``xdg-open` (many/most linuxes?) and [I think `open` on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/264395/3358272).